# Add DotNetNuke CMS to a Asp.Net MVC site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetnuke

I have a website that I developed in Asp.Net MVC. I would like to add a DotNetNuke CMS application, or something similar, so my client can do some of the content editing on their own. Is it possible to integrate dnn in to a asp.net mvc site? If so, or if not, what would be the best direction to go in?

Thanks

Comment: Off their website: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/2477/Developing-Modules-for-DotNetNuke-using-ASP-NET-MVC-Part-3-The-MvcModuleApplication-Class.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'integration' in this case is vague. You could run a DNN site for marketing and informational services and then creatively link over to your MVC app as needed and make them look and feel the same. But, you won't be able to truly have DNN run inside your MVC app.

You could take a look at: 
http://umbraco.com/  or
http://atomiccms.codeplex.com/

Those are both MVC... but I'm still not sure if you would want to really mash them together. You would probably be better off using Umbraco or even DNN (see CAbbott's link) and using DNN or some framework as the core and then building your app on it.